# A generalized/set hamiltonian cycle problem on directed graphs

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs, traveling-salesman-problem

*So this problem originally stems from the asymmetric generalized/set TSP problem, where I am interested in asking the question which or how many edges I can delete while maintaining feasability.* The problem I am interested in can be stated as follows. Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph and let $V$ be partioned into disjoint sets, i.e. $V=V_1\cup V_2 \cup \dots \cup V_m$ and $V_i\cap V_j=\emptyset, i\neq j$. The question is this:

**Q:** Does there exist a closed path $v_1v_2\dots v_mv_1$ consisting of $m+1$ vertices, which includes exactly one vertex from each of the sets $V_1, V_2, \dots, V_m$? (except for the last vertex since we want a closed path)

My question now is: Does this problem have a name? Any theorems / conditions guaranteeing the existence of such a closed path? It certainly seems a very natural problem to pose.

I'd be happy if anyone can point me towards the right **keywords**, as I was not able to come up with anything useful researching on my own.

I drew a picture for clarification with two graphs, where one graph has the described property while the other does not. The partition of $V$ is indicated by the "circles". (Naturally the graphs I am really interested in are much larger)

[image: Two >generalized/set hamiltonian cycle problem on directed graphs< examples]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems closely related to the colourful path problem.

Comment: Set TSP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_TSP_problem